# Trying to echo a variable ( $i) into another variable

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, for-loop, validation

I have a special form I have been making that uses some cusotm post types in wordpress. At one point I need to echo a variable $i into an if statement.

There is some validation stuff at the top that will look like this and the code in the loop is below. Pretty much I have been trying to get the majorCause1Error to be majorCause $i Error if you know what I mean, so all up it will be like 1-13

Edit: Sorry If it is hard to see what I am asking, I am finding it really hard to word my problem.
So there is a loop running around the li tags and it echos $i into the name etc so it becomes majorCause1 then next one majorCause2 and the next one magjorCause3 etc etc

Under the labels there is an if statement that is like - if($majorCause1Error !='') { do something } - I want this to be like if($majorCause1Error !=''){} and then the next one be like if($majorCause2Error !=''){} and then if($majorCause3Error !=''){}

Does this make more sense?

Here is a link to the site http://www.foresightaus.com.au/form/

```
if(trim($_POST['majorCause1']) === '') {
    $majorCause1Error = "Please enter a major cause.";
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $majorCause1 = trim($_POST['majorCause1']);
}

if(trim($_POST['majorCause2']) === '') {
    $majorCause2Error = "Please enter a major cause.";
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $majorCause2 = trim($_POST['majorCause2']);
}

<li class="fill-in">
    <label for="majorCause<?php echo($i); ?>"><?php echo($j); ?>. State one major cause:</label>
    <input type="text" name="majorCause<?php echo($i); ?>" id="majorCause<?php echo($i); ?>" value=""/>
    <?php if($majorCause1Error != '') { ?>
        <span class="error"><?=$majorCause1Error;?></span>
    <?php } ?>  
</li>
```

Comment: was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: tl;dr is the most obvious action in such questions. Please be concise regarding what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to be using an array but what you are referencing is called a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and is supported by PHP!

Something like this should do it

```
${"majorCause{$i}Error"}
```

Comment: Thank you! sorry this was so hard to explain I am pretty  new to PHP

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones Not a problem. But like I said, you probably want to think about using an array for something like this, that is much better coding practice

Comment: I see, I shall look into learning about php arrays. At the moment I cant really see how one would do that in an array!